# What is the use of the dwTemplateURL="http://localhost:60606/target=" calling from templates?

Tags: commerce-cloud

On each item listing page and other pages well I can see `dwMarker`, `dwPipelineURL`, `dwTemplateURL` and `dwTemplateTitle` in the comment section.

Can anyone let me know what is the usefulness of this variables?

Is it only for known purpose to identify that which isml is calling which template?

```
<!-- dwMarker="rinclude" dwPipelineTitle="Tile-Show (app_storefront_base)" dwPipelineURL="http://localhost:60606/target=/app_storefront_base/cartridge/controllers/Tile.js&amp;start=Show" dwIsController="true" dwTemplateTitle="/default/product/gridTile.isml (plugin_cartridge_merge)" dwTemplateURL="http://localhost:60606/target=/plugin_cartridge_merge/cartridge/templates/default/product/gridTile.isml" -->
```

This is the some section of the screenshot I have taken.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the extension for google chrome, and you will see the magic. its name is :

> SFCC DevTools

Also checkout here: https://github.com/redvanworkshop/sfcc-devtools

Like you can directly open the template or controller directly from your source, so you don't need to open manually or remember them.

Otherwise it is just information during development in view source.

Hope this will give more insights you.

Regards,
A